# Calling a function with different types

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on an assignment in C++ and am having difficulties with a question.
We are given a function that can take anything in as an argument.We need to call this function, UberFunction, as an int, int*,int**, and char[].

***My Code:***

```
void CallUberFunctions() {
  // There is a magic function, called "UberFunction" that is capable of taking
  // anything for an argument. You need to call "UberFunction" with the
  // following types: int, int* int** and char[]
  // You also need to call "OtherUberFunction" in the namespace
  // "uber_namespace" once, with no arguments.
  UberFunction(42);
  UberFunction((int*)42);
  UberFunction((int**)42);
  UberFunction((char[])'*');
}
```

***Here is the error:***

> home/user/Desktop/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher.cc:22:20: error: expected '(' for function-style
>         cast or type construction

I cannot get the char[] type to work properly, is my syntax above incorrect?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Perhaps you should post the actual code, and what the actual error is.

Comment: `int Uberfunction(42);` initializes an `int` called `UberFunction` with the value 42, doesn't it.  The rest then doesn't make sense.  You are probably being asked to create multiple functions with different overloaded arguments.  But you will need to show your code...

Comment: Please *edit* your original post to add the code and make sure the code is properly formatted. Pasting code into the comments section is frowned upon.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "type castint". `int*42` is ill-formed statement, so obviously it does not work. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ . Also, use 'edit' link to edit things instead of writing comments

Comment: @BaconBacon: Please!!! Update the question and format the code in the question.  Do not put it in the comments.  Transfer it from the comments to the question.  Thank you.

Comment: @user3427419, Why typecasting? I don't see the need over just giving it the right type in the first place.

Comment: @chris, for this portion to be complete I need to call the function 4 times, each time as a different type

Comment: `UberFunction((int*)42)` should work if it can take `int*`, and `UberFunction((int**)42)` should work if it can take `int**`.

Comment: @BaconBacon, Does the assignment say anything about how you get those types? It seems pretty pointless not to because there are a whole bunch of ways to get a value of any of those types.

Comment: @SHR, that worked! I can see where my problem was but I'm not sure why. I'd like to understand why that syntax worked over my   UberFunction(int*42);  why does separating (int*) from 42 make the difference? was the function argument I put in actually saying integer multiplied by 42?

Comment: @BaconBacon, Because the language says that the expression `(type)expression` is a cast and doesn't say anything about `type expression` or `type operator expression` being an expression.

Comment: @SHR, thank you. The only thing I can't get to work is the char[] type. I updated my code above to reflect what I have now.

Comment: Always dangerous to do a wholesale replace on the question. Updates and amendments are cool, but when you change damn near everything, you often render the commentary and answers obsolete and confusing. That's not fair to anyone.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the advice. I'm new to this site so these kinds of critiques are helpful for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fragment:

```
const int value = 42;
UberFunction(value); // int
UberFunction(&value); // int *
int * p_value = &value;
UberFunction(&p_value); // int * *
static const char text[] = "Hello World!\n";
UberFunction(text); // char []
```

Note that in the above example, the parameters are changing and not the return value.